# What is difference between XRM Object Model and FormContext?

Tags: javascript, dynamics-crm, crm

I want to know that difference between XRM object Model and FormContext. When we use XRM object model and when we use FormContext?

Answer (score 1):

In the latest version, [Microsoft decided to deprecate](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powerapps/developer/model-driven-apps/clientapi/clientapi-form-context) the `Xrm.Page` object - from which we used to get the form, controls and stuffs. `formContext` is the new object to be used for that purpose, which is fundamentally derived from `executionContext` using `executionContext.getFormContext`. [Read more](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powerapps/developer/model-driven-apps/clientapi/understand-clientapi-object-model)

`Xrm` object is still needed and globally available to use in your code without having to use the execution context in Client API. For example - `Xrm.WebApi` and `Xrm.Navigation` [Read more](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powerapps/developer/model-driven-apps/clientapi/clientapi-xrm)

From web resource perspective still we have to use `parent.Xrm` to get the context.

> Including a reference to ClientGlobalContext.js.aspx does not make the Xrm object available in HTML web resources. Therefore, scripts containing Xrm.* methods aren’t supported in HTML web resources. parent.Xrm.* will work if the HTML web resource is loaded in a form container. However, for other places, such as loading an HTML web resource as part of the SiteMap, parent.Xrm.* also won’t work.

[Reference](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powerapps/developer/model-driven-apps/clientapi/reference/getglobalcontext-clientglobalcontext.js.aspx)